# XQuery: How to get all nodes, that have a childnode with an attribute that is contained in a sequence

Tags: nodes, xquery

I'm very new to xQuery and could solve the first parts of my assigment, but can't get this one working.
XML: http://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1

Assignment:
Find all Customers(Kunden), that didn't buy a product of category(Kategorie) "Audio".

My approach:
Get all products of category "Audio", in one sequence, then extract all invoices(rechnung) that contain at least one invoice-position(rposition) with an Audio product. From this sequence of invoices i can then extract the distinct customer numbers and return all customer numbers of the full customer sequence($kunden), that are not listed (those didn't buy an audio product).

My main problem is, that i can't get it working to build a sequence, that contains the full invoice nodes (rechnung) which contain a product from sequence $prodaudio.
It was no problem to extract all positions with a product of type $prodaudio (see $audiorpositions).

I would greatly appreciate better approaches, or any codesnipped, that helps me understand, how to extract a sequence of all invoice nodes (rechnung), that contain at least one position with a product from sequence @prodaudio.

Since i already did some exercises i'm quite sure, that i can solve the part with the customer numbers by myself. For the moment i just need some help getting a sequence of the above mentioned invoices. Every attempt to achieve that gave me a sequence of all or none of the invoices.

The result should only contain the customer number as element.

```
let $doc := doc("https://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1")
let $prodaudio := $doc//produkt[kategorie = "Audio"]
let $kunden := $doc//kunde
for $rechnungen in $doc//rechnung
let $rpos := $doc//rechnung/rposition
let $audiorpositions := $doc//rechnung/rposition[$prodaudio/@ean = ean]
return $audiorpositions
```

xml extract:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<handelskette>
    <produkte>
        <produkt ean="0-666-4567-2-22">
            <bezeichnung>Autoschampoo</bezeichnung>
            <kategorie>Pflege</kategorie>
            <ekPreis>35</ekPreis>
            <listPreis>69</listPreis>
        </produkt>
    ...
    </produkte>
    ...
    <kunden>
        <kunde kundeNr="11111">
            <name>Roller</name>
            <bonStufe>C</bonStufe>
        </kunde>
        <kunde kundeNr="15882">
            <name>Schieber</name>
            <bonStufe>B</bonStufe>
        </kunde>
    ...
    </kunden>
    ...
    <rechnungen>
       ...
        <rechnung rechnungNr="12" datum="03.10.00">
            <bezahlt>Y</bezahlt>
            <kundeNr>11111</kundeNr>
            <filNr>6</filNr>
            <rposition>
                <ean>5-6661-000-0-00</ean>
                <einzelPreis>530</einzelPreis>
                <menge>3</menge>
            </rposition>
            <rposition>
                <ean>7-2881-760-3-70</ean>
                <einzelPreis>1300</einzelPreis>
                <menge>1</menge>
            </rposition>
            <rposition>
                <ean>0-4381-880-7-00</ean>
                <einzelPreis>1350</einzelPreis>
                <menge>1</menge>
            </rposition>
        </rechnung>
    ...
    </rechnungen>
</handelskette>
```

edit: full assignment solution:

```
declare context item := doc("https://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1");
let $kunden := //kunde,
    $rechnungen := //rechnung,
    $produkte := //produkt
for $r in $kunden[not(@kundeNr = $rechnungen[rposition/ean = $produkte[kategorie = 'Audio']/@ean]/kundeNr)]
return 
<kundeNr>
{data($r/@kundeNr)}
</kundeNr>
```

returns this output:

```
<kundeNr>15882</kundeNr>
<kundeNr>78436</kundeNr>
<kundeNr>98077</kundeNr>
<kundeNr>13451</kundeNr>
<kundeNr>99332</kundeNr>
<kundeNr>55789</kundeNr>
<kundeNr>77777</kundeNr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `declare context item := doc("https://etutor.dke.uni-linz.ac.at/etutor/XML?id=1");` I think

```
let $kunden := //kunde,
    $rechnungen := //rechnung,
    $produkte := //produkt
return
    $kunden[not(@kundeNr = $rechnungen[rposition/ean = $produkte[kategorie = 'Audio']/@ean]/kundeNr)]
```

returns those customers whose customer number does not appear on an invoice linked to a product of the category 'Audio'.

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qM2e2k/1

Comment: Thanks for great help!